# scala - how to flatten nested optional when using for loop with futures

Tags: scala, for-loop, future, for-comprehension

I'm performing a `for` loop on a range which yields a future of an optional result.
I want the resulting collection to only contain non-optional items .

But I'm left instead with `Future[Seq[Option[Result]]]`

The code looks similar to this:

```
val result = for {
        x <- 0 to numItems
      } yield {
        Future{
          ...logic...
          val intermediateResult: Option[Thing] = SomethingWhichReturnsOptionOfThing
          val s: Option[String] = intermediateResult map {
            ir => ...Do something with ir when it exists and then and map to String...
          }
          s map {
            string => Result(x, string)
          }
        }
      }
      Future.sequence(result) // Future[Seq[Option[Result]]]
```

But what i want is all the results without the `Option` i.e. `Future[Seq[Result]]`

Comment: What is wrong with `Future.sequence(result).map(_.flatten)`?

Comment: Looks correct. answer for points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `flatten` the `Seq` once the `Future` has completed:

```
Future.sequence(result).map(_.flatten)
```

This will remove all `None` values and extract the `Result` value from all `Some` results.

Note that you will no longer know which `Result` came from which item number, and `Future.sequence` may discard some errors as well, so this is not the best solution if you want accurate error handling/reporting.

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the contents of the future.

```
scala> List(Some(1), None, Some(2))
res1: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), None, Some(2))

res1.flatten
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```